# socket might be closed android error on android 6.0 only

Tags: android, sockets, bluetooth

I am using a bluetooth library I found online called multibluetooth to connect a bunch of clients. I am testing with 2 android phones, 1 is running 5.0 and the other 6.0. Running a server on the 6.0 phone and a client on the 5.0 phone works but when I reverse the roles I get this error:

```
04-07 00:27:03.507 7499-8393/com.ramimartin.sample.multibluetooth W/BT: Fallback failed. Cancelling.
java.io.IOException: read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1
  at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.readAll(BluetoothSocket.java:900)
  at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.waitSocketSignal(BluetoothSocket.java:859)
  at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.connect(BluetoothSocket.java:535)
  at com.ramimartin.multibluetooth.bluetooth.client.BluetoothConnector$FallbackBluetoothSocket.connect(BluetoothConnector.java:203)
  at com.ramimartin.multibluetooth.bluetooth.client.BluetoothConnector.connect(BluetoothConnector.java:59)
  at com.ramimartin.multibluetooth.bluetooth.client.BluetoothClient.run(BluetoothClient.java:54)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Here is the part where I am getting the error:

```
public BluetoothSocketWrapper connect() throws IOException {
    boolean success = false;
    while (selectSocket()) {
        adapter.cancelDiscovery();

        try {
            bluetoothSocket.connect();
            success = true;
            break;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //try the fallback
            try {
                bluetoothSocket = new FallbackBluetoothSocket(bluetoothSocket.getUnderlyingSocket());
                Thread.sleep(500);
                bluetoothSocket.connect();
                success = true;
                break;
            } catch (FallbackException e1) {
                Log.w("BT", "Could not initialize FallbackBluetoothSocket classes.", e);
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                Log.w("BT", e1.getMessage(), e1);
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                Log.w("BT", "Fallback failed. Cancelling.", e1);
            }
        }
    }


    if (!success) {
        throw new IOException("===> Could not connect to device: " + device.getAddress());
    }

    return bluetoothSocket;
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In case the disconnection happens while you leave the devices on sleep, this could be related with the Doze mode.

You can find more info at https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html .

Also feel free to ask me for more details.

Comment: The screen is on the whole time so doesn't that mean I have not entered doze mode? Thanks BTW

Comment: No then it's not in Doze mode-Deep sleep. If you are talking about this library https://github.com/arissa34/Android-Multi-Bluetooth-Library , it is clearly says that "This library is compatible with the Android SDK 2.3 to 5.1". So they might have issues on Android 6.0

Comment: I am trying to make it compatible with android 6.0, thats why I am asking this question.